# Deleting Gmail emails from server when deleted in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I came across several answers for this topic here but none of them seem to solve my issues. I'm running out of space on Gmail and there are some really unnecessary emails on Gmail that deserve to go. I setup Thunderbird on my windows laptop and it worked fine. I set up my Gmail as an IMAP account and I can see my emails. However, when I delete emails in Thunderbird, they are still present in Gmail. How do I have emails in Gmail delete when they are deleted in Thunderbird?

This is what my Thunderbird settings look like,

[image]

And this is what my Gmail settings look like,

[image]

Comment: You covered all the bases regarding deleting and expunging. I see a potential settings issue based on your screenshots. In Thunderbird, when deleting an email, it moves it to Trash, which should be correct. On Gmail, you have "When a message is marked as deleted as expunged from the last visible IMAP folder" set to "Archive". Typically Gmail moves messages to Trash and then deletes them after 30 days. Try adjusting this Archive setting. Also try to generate new test emails, and delete them, as you are testing different configurations.

Comment: The setting for "When a message is marked as deleted as expunged from the last visible IMAP folder" is greyed out. It can be enabled only if "Auto-Expunge off" is set in the previous setting. I'll try that though. Thanks.